# Sketching the graph and comparing it to its derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the equation:

$$C(t) = \dfrac {38t}{t^2+2}$$

and was asked to sketch it and I really have no idea where to start. I checked it with an online plotter and it was just a steep narrow line and couldn't see the rest. Can anyone tell me approximately or show with a plotter what this graph should look like?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to put the x/y limits when trying to plot, probably why I could only see the line down the middle.

Answer (score 2):

First think about what the graph of $f(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+2}$ looks like. To do this, think about what the graph of $h(t)=t^2+2$ looks like. That's easy--the graph of $h$ is an upward-opening parabola whose lowest point is at $(0,2)$, right? So you can invert this to get the graph of $f$; it will have the $x$-axis as a horizontal asymptote at $\pm\infty$; it will have a single "hump" with peak at $(0,\frac12)$.
That is, as you move from left to right, it gradually rises from the $x$-axis, reaching the peak at $(0,\frac12)$, and then gradually falls back towards the $x$-axis.

Finally, throwing in the factor of $38t$ to get $C(t)$ has the effect of forcing the peak down to the origin, and flipping the left half of the graph to below the $x$-axis because of the sign.

This means, in the end, that as you move from left to right, the curve gradually falls down from the $x$-axis, reaching a minimum somewhere to the left of the origin, then begins rising, passing through the origin, continues to rise, reaching a maximum somewhere to the right of the origin (symmetric to the minimum), then begins to fall back towards the $x$-axis you march off to the right again.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Desmos calculator](http://www.desmos.com/calculator). (I said $\frac{38x}{x^2+2}$ instead of $\frac{3t}{t^2+2}$. I think Desmos only allows the input of $x$.)

Here's what I got: (ignore the $t=1$ part of the image).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
C(t) &=&\frac{38t}{t^{2}+2} \\
\partial _{t}C(t) &=&\frac{38}{t^{2}+2}-38t\frac{2t}{(t^{2}+2)^{2}}=38\frac{%
t^{2}+2-2t^{2}}{(t^{2}+2)^{2}}=38\frac{2(1-t^{2})}{(t^{2}+2)^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that $C(t)$ is odd so it suffices to consider $t\geqslant 0$. We have $%
C(0)=0$, $C(t)>0$ for $t>0$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }C(t)=0.$ Thus we
expect a maximum. Indeed, for $t<1$ $\partial _{t}C(t)$ is positive so $C(t)$
is increasing, whereas for $t>1$ the derivative is negative and $C(t)$ is
decreasing, so $C(t)$ has the maximum $38/3$ in $1$. These results allow you
to make a rough plot.